# Default template type gives error but explicit type does not

Tags: c++, templates

My `CCustomerBulkRecordset` class is declared something like this:

```
template <class T = CRecordsetEx>
class CCustomerBulkRecordset : public T
{
    // Member declarations
};
```

And I have a method in my `CRemoteDatabase` class that looks like this:

```
template<typename T = CRecordset>
std::unique_ptr<T> ExecuteSqlQuery(LPCTSTR pszSqlQuery, UINT nOpenType = AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, DWORD dwOptions = CRecordset::none)
{
    // ...
}
```

I can use the following code to to call that method and it works fine.

```
CRemoteDatabase db;
db.Open();
auto prs = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerBulkRecordset<CRecordset>>(NULL, CRecordset::forwardOnly, CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch);
```

But the following code gives me a compile errors.

```
CRemoteDatabase db;
db.Open();
auto prs = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerBulkRecordset>(NULL, CRecordset::forwardOnly, CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch);
```

> Error C2672 'CDatabaseCommon::ExecuteSqlQuery': no matching overloaded function found
>
> Error C3206 'CDatabaseCommon::ExecuteSqlQuery': invalid template argument for 'T', missing template argument list on class template 'CCustomerBulkRecordset'

The only difference is that I'm not specifying the `CCustomerBulkRecordset` type name in the second one. But since it defaults to `CRecordset`, shouldn't the two versions work the same?

Comment: That's because `CCustomerBulkRecordset` is a *template* and not a type which is what's expected. If you try `CCustomerBulkRecordset<>` does it work then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, it does. Isn't a template also a type?

Comment: A template is a template and a type is a type. Those are two different things.

Comment: A template is a higher-kind type, you can regard it as a type constructor, or a function that maps vectors of types into types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
template<typename T = CRecordset>
std::unique_ptr<T> ExecuteSqlQuery(...)
```

`T` is a template parameter.  That means it must be deduced to a single type, or provided a type explicitly.  When you do

```
auto prs = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerBulkRecordset<CRecordset>>(...);
```

You give it the type `CCustomerBulkRecordset<CRecordset>`.  When you do

```
auto prs = db.ExecuteSqlQuery<CCustomerBulkRecordset>(...);
```

You are giving it `CCustomerBulkRecordset`, which is not a type, but instead it is a template.  In order to pass a template to a function you need to use a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter).

The presence of the default template parameter does not turn `CCustomerBulkRecordset` into `CCustomerBulkRecordset<CRecordset>`.  In order to get that you need `CCustomerBulkRecordset<>` as the `<>` indicates you want to instantiate the template with the default value.

Comment: But what is the purpose of being able to specify a default type? How is using the default different than specifying it explicitly?

Comment: @JonathanWood I've just added how you would get the default.